# Suma acumulativa de una columna de un DATAFRAME

Tags: r

Tengo este dataframe

| Mes | Ventas Mensuales |
| --- | --- |
| Enero | 250,000.00 |
| Febrero | 100,000.00 |
| Marzo | 50,000.00 |
| Abril | 25,000.00 |
| Mayo | 450,000.00 |
| Junio | 89,500.00 |

Necesito agregar la columna total como sumatoria acumulada al dataframe.

| Mes | Ventas Mensuales | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Enero | 250,000.00 | 250,000.00 |
| Febrero | 100,000.00 | 350,000.00 |
| Marzo | 50,000.00 | 400,000.00 |
| Abril | 25,000.00 | 425,000.00 |
| Mayo | 450,000.00 | 875,000.00 |
| Junio | 89,500.00 | 964,500.00 |

Lo he intentando con un bucle for, pero no lo logré.

Comment: Pareciera ser que lo que necesitas es básicamente una suma acumulada para generar una nueva columna, por ej: `cumsum(tu_tf$tu_columna_a_sumar)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En R en cuanto a manipulación de datos hay dos o tres "escuelas" para escribir código, por un lado tenemos lo que es `R base` que son las soluciones de código `R` "de fabrica", la otra es la escuela `tidyverse` que hace uso de este metapaquete y por último podemos considerar a `data.table` otro de los paquetes comunes. En cuanto a tu pregunta, entiendo que lo que buscas es una suma acumulada.

Por ejemplo:

```
df <- data.frame(Mes = c('Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo'), total=c(100, 200, 300))
df

      Mes total
1   Enero   100
2 Febrero   200
3   Marzo   300
```

##### 1. R base:

```
df$acumulado <- cumsum(df$total)
```

##### 2. A lo "tidyverse":

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(acumulado = cumsum(total))
```

##### 3. Con `data.table`

Esta solución requiere transformar el `data.frame` en un `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt[, acumulado := cumsum(total)]
dt
```

Todas las alternativas generan una salida similar a esta:

```
      Mes total acumulado
1   Enero   100       100
2 Febrero   200       300
3   Marzo   300       600
```

Comentarios adicionales:

- La suma acumulativa depende del orden, por lo que siempre deberemos ordenar en primer lugar antes de aplicar la sumatoria
- Como toda operación en R hay que contemplar la eventual existencia de valores faltantes o `NA`, `cumsum()` no tiene ningún tratamiento para estos valores como si lo tienen otras funciones, un valor `NA` si aparece arrastrará este valor hasta el final. Por lo que convendrá hacer un remplazo de los `NA` a 0 previo a la suma, por ejemplo: `df$total <- ifelse(is.na(df$total), 0, df$total)`

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio, muy claro.